# How to get all pyodide globals in JavaScript

Tags: pyodide

According to the [api docs](https://pyodide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/api-reference.html), pyodide provides a way to get a user defined function or variable through `pyodide.globals.x` as an example (where x is defined by the user). I want to be able to get all globals at once but there is nothing in the docs about this. I was wondering if there is perhaps a clever way of doing this?

EDIT:

If you type `pyodide.globals` in developer tools there is no reference to x but if you type `pyodide.globals.x` (and it is defined) you get the value. How does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pyodide.globals` is a PyProxy object that exposes the Python `globals()` dictionary to JavaScript. All attribute access will be proxied to the python dictionary,
see the [documentation](https://pyodide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/type-conversions.html#python-from-javascript) for more details.

The easiest way to get all globals is to call `pyodide.globals.toJs()` which will return a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object with all the entries. Note that this currently only works with the development version of pyodide or the upcoming 0.17.0 release.

Comment: Is there a CDN URL for v17? The docs point to v16

Comment: yes, you can change the v0.16.0 to `dev` in the URL